# Cannot extract a column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I have imported with pandas.

```
            Open      High       Low     Close     Volume
Date                                                         
2020-10-09  115.2800  117.0000  114.9200  116.9700   99544600
2020-10-08  116.2500  116.4000  114.5901  114.9700   83477150
2020-10-07  114.6200  115.5500  114.1300  115.0800   96848990
2020-10-06  115.7000  116.1200  112.2500  113.1600  161498200
2020-10-05  113.9100  116.6500  113.5500  116.5000  106243800
              ...       ...       ...       ...        ...
2010-10-15   10.9800   11.2500   10.8896   11.2407  916757153
2010-10-14   10.7746   10.8025   10.7286   10.7968  433258667
2010-10-13   10.7214   10.7843   10.7071   10.7193  621062152
2010-10-12   10.5504   10.6964   10.4461   10.6621  556451057
2010-10-11   10.5264   10.6157   10.5214   10.5486  426705269
```

I'm having difficulty in trying to reference a column. I thought it should be as simple as `dataset['Close']`. Yet whenever I try this, I get `KeyError: 'Close'`.

The exact line I used to create the dataset is `dataset = pd.read_csv('AAPL.csv', index_col="Date", parse_dates=True)`

As requested AAPL.csv (first few lines):

```
Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume
10/09/2020,115.28,117,114.92,116.97,99544600
10/08/2020,116.25,116.4,114.5901,114.97,83477150
10/07/2020,114.62,115.55,114.13,115.08,96848990
```

Comment: Could you add the first few lines of the AAPL.csv line in the question?

Comment: You can also check the current columns' labels using print(dataset.columns.tolist()) - if there are any blanks involved, you should then see those...

Comment: check `not isinstance(dataset.columns, pd.MultiIndex)` and `'Close' in dataset.columns` , maybe `'close'` instead `'Close'` or maybe there are blanks in column labels. You could do: `dataset.columns = dataset.columns.str.replace(' ', '')` and then : `dataset['Close']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tgrandje nailed it. Using `print(dataset.columns.tolist())` I discovered that there were indeed spaces in the names. Fixed by reformatting the source file.